# Counting Polygon Centroids in Polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have two tables in PostgreSQL 13:

- `hexbin` table with geom field (red)
- `sites` table with geom field (blue)

[image]

I want to return a table with the hexbin geometries and a total count of where the sites fall within the hexbin (counting site centers in hexbins).

The following code does appear to return me what I require:

```
SELECT hexbin.gid, hexbin.geom, count(*) AS site_total
    FROM sites, hexbin
    WHERE ST_intersects(hexbin.geom, (ST_PointOnSurface(sites.geom)))
GROUP BY hexbin.gid
```

[image]

Can this approach be improved?

From looking at other samples and my previous experience with SQL Server Spatial, should I be incorporating a join to improve performance?

Comment: No, technically this is the way, and it's [a `JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-join.html) already. It's good practice to use the verbose `JOIN` syntax, though. Maybe use `COUNT(sites.*)`.

Comment: Do you have spatial indices for both table? You can use EXPLANE to check the execution of your query (e.g. indices are used).  It may be faster if you make a fast decision using bounding boxes (e. g. WHERE hexbin.geom && sites.geom and ST_Intersects(....)

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided test data to check the different options for optimizing your query and yet, splitting your query into simple subqueries can lead to a 2-n times optimization, so check my assumption on your data and for this run the query:

```
WITH
    tbla AS (SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geom) geom FROM sites),
    tblb AS (SELECT a.gid, (a.geom) geom, count(*) AS sites_total FROM hexbin a
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbla b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)) GROUP BY a.gid)
    SELECT a.gid, a.geom, SUM(a.sites_total) AS sum_sites FROM tbla b, tblb a 
    WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, (b.geom)) GROUP BY a.gid, a.geom
```

Check your result.

There's always room for optimization as long as the query execution speed doesn't turn to "0".

Comment: Cyril, this looks great - thank you.  Testing now.

Comment: Seems to work well on small sets of data.  But times out with larger datasets (Hexbins - >50k records), whereas the original SQL still parses in less than a second.  Will break your query apart and investigate further.

Comment: It may still need to look for alternative approaches, my approach optimizes and narrows the amount of geodata, at the code level, namely: 1) converts polygons to points, getting rid of unnecessary coordinates; 2) gets rid of unnecessary hexagons, if any, and 3) selects hexagons and summarizes the abbonnet count...also possible to play with the technical capabilities of the PC, but only cautiously...

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: With large sets of geodata, everyone gets a timeout...:-)